# Python extracting right data from nested dictionary

Tags: python, json, sqlite

I have created a database called "entities_data" using sqlite3

```
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect('entities_data.sqlite')
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS entities')
cur.execute('''
    CREATE TABLE entities (
        id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, tweet_id INTEGER, type TEXT, 
        value INTEGER, start_index INTEGER, end_index INTEGER, FOREIGN KEY (tweet_id) REFERENCES tweets (id))
''')
conn.close()
```

i have a JSON file database that records all tweets, a simplified version of it with just 2 of the tweets looks like this

`[ {"id_1" : "123", "created_at" : "monday", "tweet_text" : "#hi my name is john", "entities": {"hashtags": [{"text": "hi", "indices": [0, 2]}], "symbols": [], "user_mentions": [], "urls": [{"url": "link_1",[211, 234]}] }`

`{"id_2" : "456", "created_at" : "tuesday", "tweet_text" : "#food i am eating now", "entities": {"hashtags": [{"text": "food", "indices": [0, 5]}], "symbols": [],  "user_mentions": [], "urls": [], "media": "img_1"} }]`

With this, i want to pull out the keys from the entities keys only when there are values in it. For example in Id_1, ["hashtags", "urls] will be pulled out, while id_2 will pull out ["hashtags", "media"].

with the code below, i manage to pull out all the keys in "entities", however i keep getting an error as they are str objects.

```
conn = sqlite3.connect('entities_data.sqlite')
cur = conn.cursor()
for records in data:
    for entity in records['entities']:
        print(entity)
```

Comment: share the full error details please. where `data` is defined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Solution 1: List comprehension

You can use list comprehension for this

```py
keys_with_values = [
    [key for key, value in item['entities'].items() if value]
    for item in data
]
print(keys_with_values)
```

Output:

```
[['hashtags', 'urls'], ['hashtags', 'media']]
```

#### Solution 2: Ordinary for loop

```
keys_with_values = []

for item in data:
    current_keys = []

    for key, value in item['entities'].items():
        if value:
            current_keys.append(key)

    keys_with_values.append(current_keys)

print(keys_with_values)
```

Output:

- Same as above

Comment: Ahh thank you this works!! sorry i am just a beginner, but is there a simpler way to write this for loop?

Comment: Solution 1's usage of list comprehension is actually the simplest-looking way, although might be a bit complicated for beginners. I added an alternative Solution 2 using the usual for loop. Does it work on your side too?

Comment: Hi both of the solutions works perfectly on my side! And thank you, from solution 2 i would be able to understand how solution 1 is being coded. Really appreciate your help :)

Comment: Glad it helped you. If it's all the answer you need, you might want to accept it as the answer :) https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers